# C# Математическая задача. Луч и точка

Tags: c#, математика

Есть точка X1 и Y1 (чекпойнт в реальной программе), есть луч, он начинается в точке X2 и Y2 и в направлении A градусов в радианах (игровая камера в реальной программе). На сколько градусов нужно повернуть камеру чтобы луч смотрел в точку X1 Y1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через векторное и скалярное произведение текущего направляющего вектора и целевого направления (результат в радианах)

```
rotangle = atan2(cos(A)*(Y1-Y2)-sin(A)*(X1-X2), cos(A)*(X1-X2)+sin(A)*(Y1-Y2))
```